# How to know when the list of faces is empty?

Tags: python

I used this program to detect faces in video taken from my webcam, everything is working fine and a rectangle is showing over any face that appears in the frame.
I am using this code to send the x values of the face to an Arduino microcontroller to manipulate a servo. when there are no faces, the x value remains the same as the last time when there was a face.
How can I know that there are no faces in a frame so I can tell the servo to remain at the same position?

**This is the code**

```
import cv2
import sys

cascPath = "haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml"
faceCascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cascPath)

video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(1)
while True:
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = video_capture.read()

    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    faces = faceCascade.detectMultiScale(
        gray,
        scaleFactor=1.1,
        minNeighbors=5,
        minSize=(30, 30),
        flags=cv2.CASCADE_SCALE_IMAGE
    )

    # Draw a rectangle around the faces
    for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (0, 255, 0), 2)
        if x>=300:
            print("right")
        elif x<=240:
           print("left")
        elif x<300 and x>240:
            print('mid')
        else:
            print('no face detected')
    
    # Display the resulting frame
    cv2.imshow('Video', frame)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

# When everything is done, release the capture
video_capture.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I am trying to print *"mid"* when the face is in the middle of the frame, *"left"* when it's on the left and *"right"* when it's on the right.
It's working fine but if the face is on the right and **disappear**, "right" will still be printed and *"no faces found"* will never be printed.
I am expecting something to tell me that there is no faces in the frame.

Comment: welcome. [tour], [ask], [mre]. MRE implies debugging your own code, with a debugger. you'll notice when a list is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You iterate over detected faces here

```
for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
```

And inside that loop you print "no faces detected", that does not make sense.
IF no faces are detected THEN faces is an empty list, so the `for` loop does NOT get executed at all.

Insert those lines before the `for` loop:

```
if len(faces) == 0:
    print("No faces detected!")
```

- check if faces is an empty list
- if that's the case print that no faces are detected